# adding actions to Eclipse toolbar

Tags: eclipse-plugin, toolbar

I have 2 plugins that add 2 actionSet in the eclipse toolbar. I'd like to
put them in the same group. What should I specify in the "toolbarPath" attribute?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Anything you want as long as they match. The toolbarPath attribute will create the new group if it doesn't exist already. So if you make a unique name and give it to both actions they will appear in their own group together.